# What the mechanism use to integrate python with other languages (.Net, Java ....)

Tags: java, .net, python, embed

Somebody talking the python's code can embed into C#'s code. What the mechanism to do that? please explain for me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/implementations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, depending on which languages you want to interoperate with.

- **.Net/CLR Languages** - [Iron Python](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=IronPython) provides an implementation of Python running on the CLR. Allows you to use other CLR assemblies and embed a python scripting engine in your code
- **Java/JVM Based Languages** - [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) provides an implementation on the JVM and allows you to use Java classes and call to call into jython as a scripting language using [JSR 223 - Scripting for the Java Platform](https://scripting.dev.java.net/)
- **C/C++/Perl/etc, etc** The [Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator](http://www.swig.org/) allows you to interop between C based languages and others, including .Net and Java. It's very good for C++, C and COM - other languages are little trickier - but worth checking out if you need to use CPython with .Net or Java

Answer (score 5):

Use [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) for integration with .net. Likewise, [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) integrates with Java.

Comment: Thank ammoQ for answer, but i want to know how IronPython embed python's code to .Net's code?

Answer (score 2):

And [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) for integration with Java.